# Monaco editor - Pre-populate find control with text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I'm hosting a Monaco editor in my React app.

So far, I've got the editor to open the find control when the editor has mounted, but I need to pre-populate it with some text.

The bit of code at the moment looks like this:

```
... 

class CodeEditorMonaco extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.editorDidMount = this.editorDidMount.bind(this)
    this.editor = null
  }

  editorDidMount (editor, monaco) {
    editor.focus()
    editor.getAction('actions.find').run()
  } 

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='code-editor'>
        <MonacoEditor
          width='100%'
          height='75vh'
          language='json'
          editorDidMount={this.editorDidMount}
          ref={editor => { this.editor = editor }}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
...
```

I don't think the API documentation is clear as to whether this is possible or not.

My first instinct was to do
    `editor.getAction('actions.find').run('text here')`
but that doesn't seem to work

When you highlight a word in the editor itself, and then press `CMD+F` you get the find control pre-populated with the text, so I believe it's possible to achieve.

Any help would be appreciated.

Find control:
[image: Find control]

Comment: Could really do with some help with this please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a way to do what you want and it's by doing exactly what you already described:

1. Make a text selection for the term you want to search for

   `editor.setSelection(new monaco.Range(18, 8, 18, 15));`
2. Trigger the find action

   `editor.trigger('', 'actions.find');`

   or

   `editor.getAction('actions.find').run('');`

Comment: is it possible to open the find window in replace mode? Thank you!!

Comment: @cat_in_hat I saw there's another action called `editor.action.startFindReplaceAction` which may be what you need for the replace window. If it doesn't work then check this link for more possible actions: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/12134ce9978b156d6521bea84bce28a70fe90352/src/vs/editor/contrib/find/findModel.ts#L56:L75

Answer (score 10):

You can try it with Monaco playground.

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "{\n\t\"dependencies\": {\n\t\t\n\t}\n}\n",
    language: "json"
});

const model = editor.getModel();
const range = model.findMatches('d')[0].range;

editor.setSelection(range);
editor.getAction('actions.find').run();
```

First, get the range of the string you want to find from your model.
Second, set selection.
Third, trigger select action.